# What is the reason of subsurf making hard edges?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm modeling chassis of a car and I've noticed, that in some areas subsurf suprisingly keeps hard edges:

[image: Hard edges]

Even though wireframe may not look very simple, there is still no reason for those:

[image: Wireframe]

I checked the usual suspects:

- Bevel value for edges
- Duplicated edges and/or vertices (Merge by distance)

I couldn't find the cause. I suspect I might have pressed some keyboard shortcut, which switched something, because I used Blender a long time ago and a lot of keyboard shortcuts changed since. It's hard to tell though without knowing what to search.

How can I make those edges soft again?

Comment: maybe you have inverted normals? Select all and press Shift N. If it doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes it is probably due to normals, try to enable face orientation and check your topology, or share your file as @moonboots says